# Is this a contradiction in The Giver?

Tags: the-giver

*The Giver*, Chapter 2, Page 23:

> "Lily," her mother said fondly, "you're very close to being an Eight, and when you're an Eight, your comfort object will be taken away. It will be recycled to the younger children. You should be starting to go off to sleep without it.

*The Giver*, Chapter 13, Page 127: (This is after the ceremony, FYI)

> "Lily," he asked that evening when **his sister took her comfort object, the stuffed elephant, from the shelf,** "did you know that once there really were elephants? Live ones?

Lily shouldn't have the comfort object, as she is an Eight at this point. Is there an explanation somewhere, or is this a contradiction? This has been bugging me for days.

Comment: As long as it happens before she's a Nine there's no contradiction

Comment: See the question. "When you're an **Eight**, your comfort object will..." and "Ch. 13, p. 127 (This is **after the ceremony**, FYI"

Comment: Right. It says when she's an Eight, not as soon as she becomes an Eight. She's an Eight for a whole year, and if the object is removed during that year, then it will have happened **when** she's an Eight.

Comment: Given that the society of The Giver is shown to be a little bureaucratically bound and inefficient, I wouldn't be surprised if CreationEdge's answer was the correct one.